# Generate path for \includegraphics with if-else macro

Tags: macros, conditionals, plot, includegraphics

I would like to have a single option/macro (true/false or similar) that determines, from which folder to choose plots. 
There's only 2 folders for each plot.
Mainly need this to switch between low resolution/high resolution  plots to speedup viewing/compilation of document while writing.
With low resolution plots viewing is way faster (I use quite old notebook).
I came up with some code, but it gives these errors:
1) `File ended while scanning use of`__xparse_grab_G_trailing:w.
2) ==> `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

If I use commented `\includegraphics` line with hard-coded path, it works of course.

The `testPlot.png` file is located under `plots/smallPlots` folder.
I also usually use `\addpic` macro (it generated `\includegraphics` code) instead of `\includegraphics`, but even this simplified version doesn't work.

Thank you!

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

 \newcommand{\IsUseFullSizePlots}{yes} % Path switching parameter. Macro either defined or commented
\NewDocumentCommand{\Path}{g}{%
plots/\ifdef{\IsUseFullSizePlots}{originalFullSizePlots}{smallPlots} % from etoolbox package
}

\begin{document}

 Path = \Path % checking
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth, clip]{\Path/testPlot}
%    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth, clip]{plots/smallPlots/testPlot}

\end{document}
```

---

Code for the `\addpic` macro (don't understand really how it works, works though :):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

% the user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\addpic}{m}
 {
  \group_begin: % localize the changes to the variables
  \simonson_pic:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

% the key-value interface
\keys_define:nn { simonson/pic }
 {
  placement .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_placement_tl,
  placement .initial:n = htp,
  width .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_width_tl,
  width .initial:n = 1,
  options .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_options_tl,
  image .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_image_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_label_tl,
 }

% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simonson_pic:n
 {
  % set the keys from the argument
  \keys_set:nn { simonson/pic } { #1 }
  % start the figure environment
  \__simonson_start_figure:V \l_simonson_pic_placement_tl
  \centering
  % include the image
  \__simonson_pic_image:VVV
    \l_simonson_pic_width_tl % the text width fraction
    \l_simonson_pic_options_tl % other options
    \l_simonson_pic_image_tl % the image name
  % the caption
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl
   {
    \caption{\l_simonson_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   {
    \caption[\l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl]{\l_simonson_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   % the label
%      In \ addpics \ macro:\ label=\l_simonson_pic_label_tl %for test(my code)
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_simonson_pic_label_tl
    {
     \label{\l_simonson_pic_label_tl}
    }
   % end the figure environment

   %### %for parser to ignore
   \end{figure}
   %###
}

% syntactic sugar: we want some token lists to be expanded before usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simonson_start_figure:n
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__simonson_start_figure:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simonson_pic_image:nnn
 {
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__simonson_pic_image:nnn { VVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

===========================================================
usage example

```
    \addpic{
    width=0.3,
    image=example-image,
    caption={This is an example image, and a comma in the caption},
    label=one,
    }
```

Comment: Do `\newcommand{\Path}{plots/\ifdef{\IsUseFullSizePlots}{originalFullSizePlots}{smallPlots}}`

Comment: This is also code for \addpic macro (not used above, would be cool if could use it instead of \includegraphics though).

Comment: An example of how you use `\addpic` would be better. In other words, a minimal example.

Comment: sure, 1 second:)

Comment: posted \addpic example

Comment: egreg, the way you suggested here works even together with addpic macro. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use the if/then logic to set `\GraphicsPath`, and then `\includegraphics` wouldn't need to change. (as long as the file names in the different folders were the same).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your definition of `\Path`, with a (unused) optional argument.

Just do

```
%\newcommand{\Path}{plots/originalFullSizePlots} % for final version
\newcommand{\Path}{plots/smallPlots}            % for draft
```

and switch the comments when you want to produce the final version.

The `\addpic` call should be like

```
\addpic{
  width=0.3,
  image=\Path/testPlot,
  caption={This is an example image, and a comma in the caption},
  label=one,
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I keep plots for different chapters/sections in corresponding chapter folders. There's quite a lot of plots, and I keep them structured in subfolders. Don't really see how to use such a simple approach it for now